# Express redirect client on POST with res.render

Tags: express, post, get, xmlhttprequest, render

Im trying to redirect the client after I send a POST request like this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('POST', '/search', true);
var searchData = {
    key: search.value,
}

xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify(searchData));
```

server:

```
app.post('/search', (req, res) =>{
    console.log('render search')
    res.render('search')
})
```

I get the "render search" log, but nothing happens client side and I have no clue why, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rendering a template is **not** the same thing as redirecting.

Comment: I see, so I have to redirect the client with res.redirect(page link)?, Ive tried that but nothing happens, Im probably missing something very obvious

Comment: And note that would be responding to an AJAX request, **not** an actual navigation - the client's page won't change unless you update it from the JS.